# Entityframework 6.1 connection: Domain suffix and hostname/port resolution for Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Used ef for the first time and published an application who access a oracle db. all works fine.
Have to change now the networksettings on the server and add a domain suffix.
All other applications (without ef, direct connect via ado.net) still work fine, the app with ef does not anymore...
Error: ORA 12541 No Listener cause EF takes the wrong IP/Port.

How to resolve this ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the slqnet.ora:

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES)